# Redirect to a default nested state in AngularJS with ui-router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm dealing with a redirection with `ui-router`.

I have a menu with items. When I chose one of them it redirects to the correspondant html template to load. Each html template contains tabs.

I would like to open a default tab for each item in the menu.

Here are my states:

```
$stateProvider

.state('app.my', {
  url:'/my/:numeral',
  templateUrl:
    function (stateParams) {
        return stateParams.numeral + '.html';
    }
})

.state('app.my.first', {
  url:'/:filter',
  templateUrl:'list-results.html',
  controller: 'FilterCtrl',
    controllerAs: 'results'
})

.state('app.my.second', {
  url:'/:filter',
  templateUrl:'list-results.html',
  controller: 'FilterCtrl',
    controllerAs: 'results'
});
```

Here I created a [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/oIQDIhx2vrp1o01Xz3EL?p=preview) which works fine when I click on tabs manually.
My goal is to set a default open tab for each menu item.

http://plnkr.co/edit/oIQDIhx2vrp1o01Xz3EL?p=preview

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

edit `ui-sref` values like that:

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills">
    <li>
      <a class="nav-tab" ui-sref-active="active" ui-sref="app.my.first({numeral:'first',filter:'draft'})">First</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a class="nav-tab" ui-sref-active="active" ui-sref="app.my.second({numeral:'second',filter:'draft'})">Second</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
```